# How to dynamically add a decorator after angularjs bootstrap

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way in angularjs to dynamically (after angular bootstrap) to enhance a service by proxying it using the `decorator` pattern.

In the following [plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/MV6ddlkEmOBVjmsDMhFq) I can overload my default search service (google based) but this relies on the declaration/addition of the overloading module (the yahoo one) using the `app.requires` dependencies of the application before the angular app is bootstrapped. This does not work once the angular application is already bootstrapped, as demoed when clicking on `duckduckgo` button.

I must do the decoration dynamically by injecting javascript code into the application in a migration scenario where the webapp has to be embed into a java client (using JavaFX webview) and where some actions (the ones introduced dynamically) have to replace standard behavior of the webapp.

I have tried to use some technics described by [Ifeanyi Isitor in his blog](http://ify.io/lazy-loading-in-angularjs/) without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible method might be to get a hold of the `injector` of the currently running application (as described at the bottom of the documentation for [`angular.injector`](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/docs/api/ng/function/angular.injector)). This is done by using `angular.element` on an element of the currently running app to get its `injector()`.

To easily get a hold of this element, if you were to give the tag on which you've declared your app the id of `mcfoggy-application-search`:

```
<div ng-app="mcfoggy.application.search" id="mcfoggy-application-search">...</div>
```

... you could `.getElementById()` and clobber the originally defined service a bit like this (as per your plunkr):

```
console.info('interpreting duckduckGoService.js');

var appElement = document.getElementById('mcfoggy-application-search');
var injector = angular.element(appElement).injector();

injector.invoke(['SearchService', '$log', function(SearchService, $log) {
      // replace search in SearchService
      SearchService.search = function(terms) {
          var duckduckGoSearch = 'https://duckduckgo.com/?q=' + encodeURI(terms);
          $log.info("search called: " + duckduckGoSearch);
          // $window.location.href = duckduckGoSearch;
      };
}]);
```

Maybe not as pretty as decoration, but it seems to work!

[Updated plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/9auvdU5Sj16LhHPE63AI?p=preview)

Comment: Without any other answer I'll grant you the bounty but will not accept the answer as it does not use the decorator. Thanks for your time & help.

Comment: Thanks, @MatthieuBROUILLARD - hope it's at least of some help. I would be interested to further investigate how this method compares to what's possible with decoration (I will try and do so when I have more time); are you able to expand on what limitations you found with the above approach when applied to your less-simplified actual code? Happy to brainstorm further solutions.